# 24 V AC circuit for a hydronic space heating system

Tags: polarity

I just purchased a home with a gas fired boiler space heating system that is split into 3 main zones (3 circ pumps).  I am having difficulty getting heat to parts of the house and I want to first make sure there are no wiring errors.

The thermostats are Honeywell TL8100 series, the transformers are Honeywell AT20B1056 and the zone valves are Honeywell 4 wire (2 yellow and 2 red) V8043.  When there is a call for heat at the thermostat, power is sent to open the valve (yellow wires).  This in turn closes an end switch on the valve (red wires) and power is sent to the relay to energize the coil to switch on both the pump (110 V) and the boiler (24 V AC signal).

In one zone, I have the transformer's **red** wire going directly to the thermostat and in another zone I have another transformer with a **black** wire going to its thermostat.

Does this really matter?  Is polarity an issue here?

Comment: Red and black would indicate a polarity, it would be a poor choice of colours for the AC output of a transformer. And indeed, all pictures I find online of this  transformer show it having white/black wires, no red. Are you sure you're not mistaken?

Comment: Use paragraphs to break walls of text into logical units for ease of reading. It's a skill worth learning. 'V' for volt. Fixed.

Comment: All my low voltage wiring is indeed black and red.  No white.